# IMagic object creation shows error?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

I just try to integrate ImageMagick into my PHP project. I installed and just execute the sample files that they provided with the imagick-3.0.0RC1 zip file. But it shows

Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\imagick-3.0.0RC1\imagick-3.0.0RC1\examples\watermark.php on line 9

this kind of an error how can I avoid that. I cant see any class including section on that page. How to include the class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the ImageMagick PHP extension. According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) there is no prebuilt extension for Windows so you'll probably have to configure and compile it yourself.

Comment: yes I installed imagic PHP extension and copy paste the dll to the php /dll folder. after that edited and enabled php.ini file. I checked it with command prompt. Imagic is installed in my machine but still it shows the class missing error why?

Comment: Have you restarted your web server after the changes? What does phpinfo() say?